# I need a formula so that if a value in column a change then add +1 to the value of another column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a list of product codes in column A. In column B i have a list with text values which i will call "positions" (1B 02 1 etc). In column C I give a serial number for each product code (52001001). My list is sorted by column B. All code products in the same position must have the same serial number. So what i need is a formula when the "position" change, to add +1 to the serial numbers in column C. I hope you understand me and sorry for my English.

Comment: you need to save your last value to another cell (say BOB), compare BOB and the current value. IF EQUAL then no change - IF NOT EQUAL, then store new value in BOB and increment your desired cell value by 1.

Comment: @OP: What did you try thus far?

Comment: MikeDask: If you are the same person as @Michael Dask, flag the question (click on "flag") and ask to have your accounts merged. P.S. Showing a sample of data _in columns_ would help.

Answer (score 0):

In language, you want (as I understand it): IF A11 is equal to "1B 22 1 5", THEN show the value of B10 ELSE add 1 to B10.

In Excel, this can be expressed as the following formula: `=IF( A11 = "1B 22 1 5"; B10; B10+1 )`

See [Excel's help on the IF function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/if-HP005209118.aspx).